# Get a JSONObject Value from another view

Tags: java, android

So i have a class called `recuperationJson` which store json data into a `JsonObject` and display them after parsing in some `TextView`s in my main_activity.xml, it works well, here's a part of the code:

```
jObj = new JSONObject(valeurARenvoyer);
hauteur = jObj.getString("Niveau_Eau");//se place a l'endroit Niveau_Eau du json et obtient le string apres les :
// debit = jObj.getString("Debit");
date = jObj.getString("Date_Releve");
batterie = jObj.getString("Charge_Batterie");
presence = jObj.getString("Etat_Perimetrique");
```

I would like to display one of these values in another class, called `BatteryActivity`, which display another view called activity_battery.xml

For now this view only display my menu and background, i've done some tried but i didn't find. I saw some example which implements `Serializable`, but i don't get how to do it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pretend you only want to pass a String through activities

in ActivityA:

```
String myString = "my text view string";
Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
i.putStringExtra("MyStringKey",myString);
startActivity(i);
```

in ActivityB:

```
String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyStringKey");
myTextView.setText(myString);
```

If you want to pass a whole object I would advise you to use Gson

in ActivityA:

```
MyModel myModel = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonString,MyModel.class);
Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("MyModelKey",myModel);
startActivity(i);
```

in ActivityB:

```
MyModel myModel = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyModelKey");
myTextView.setText(myModel.getName());
```

Take in consideration that your model must `implement Serializable`for this example

Comment: With your first method it works, but my Activity A start my Activity B, and i want to be able to stay on my Activity A without swapping to Activity B.

Comment: If you are not swapping to activityB why do you want to set a value if activityB isn't created?

Comment: Any advance in your problem?

Comment: My Main activity is the one that we call "A". It get/parse and display value on a A_activity.xml. I got another Activity "B" which need to display one value from the activity A, but in my B_activity.xml. So here i can get the value from A and display it on B, but it's impossible to stay on the A activity because of the startActivity(i).

Comment: I've used my Menu toolbar to call the start activity with the intent when i click on a menu option and it works, Thx for help :)

Comment: The thing is about handling the activities state. You only pass the value to activityB once you start it, not before

Answer (score 0):

Create a class "Data" with fields you want from your JSON, and implements Serializable in this class.

Then pass the new object created to your Activity B with an Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(intent);
```